# Generating the next frame with a convolutional LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, convolution

I've been struggling to find good tutorials or examples demonstrating convolutional LSTM.

I'm trying to build a model which will generate the next frame based on a series of previous frames. The use of TimeDistributed and ConvLSTM2D is a little tricky.

Can anyone share examples?

Comment: Use either `TimeDistributed(Conv2D)+TimeDistributed(Flatten)+LSTM` or just `ConvLSTM2D`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_lstm.py

In the above link, they used videos of shape(n_samples=1200, n_frames=15, n_row_image=40, n_col_image=40, n_channels=1) to predict another video frame in the test set. They used ConvLSTM2D which is a nice feature that can be used for frame prediction or any other kind of video related deep learning problems.